# why isnt it let me crop my image into a circle with this code?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

This is throwing an error. It is my first time trying to do this part, so bear with me.

My error is at `cell.image.frame...`:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];
    if (cell == nil) cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:@"cell"];

    PFObject *group = groups[indexPath.row];
     //if(group[PF_GROUP_LOGO] != nil){
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), ^{ // go to a background thread to load the image and not interfere with the UI
       UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:group[PF_GROUP_LOGO]]]];
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ // synchronize back to the main thread to update the UI with your loaded image
            cell.layer.cornerRadius = cell.image.frame.size.width/2;
            cell.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
            cell.imageView.image = image;
            cell.textLabel.text = group[PF_GROUP_NAME];
            cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d users", (int) [group[PF_GROUP_MEMBERS] count]];
            cell.detailTextLabel.textColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];

        });
    });
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: What's the error? And what line specifically is it happening on?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out! I was just referencing cell. in an inappropriate way.

```
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
{

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];
    if (cell == nil) cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:@"cell"];

    PFObject *group = groups[indexPath.row];
     //if(group[PF_GROUP_LOGO] != nil){
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), ^{ // go to a background thread to load the image and not interfere with the UI
       UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:group[PF_GROUP_LOGO]]]];
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ // synchronize back to the main thread to update the UI with your loaded image

            cell.imageView.image = image;
            cell.imageView.layer.cornerRadius = cell.imageView.frame.size.height /2;
            cell.imageView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
            cell.imageView.layer.borderWidth = 0;
            cell.textLabel.text = group[PF_GROUP_NAME];
            cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d users", (int) [group[PF_GROUP_MEMBERS] count]];
            cell.detailTextLabel.textColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];

        });
    });
    return cell;

}
```

Comment: Using the dispatch  async this way you risk to have problems when the cell is reused. If the user scrolls fast, then you will have multiple dispatch that executes at the same time, and it is possible that the first call will end after the second. This will lead to a bug.

Comment: This led me to another question, Ill post it real fast on another thread.